# First Addon help - Cycling through windows with for loop

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am making my first firefox extension today.  So far I have done a little...but now I would like to count the number of firefox windows the user has open (for example 3)  I can count tabs, that is easy so far...but I can't seem to find how to cycle through windows and count them (windows != tabs, like tabs are within windows, sorry, I hope this makes sense, even mozilla confuses it in their coding) I think basically, I am lost for the method name...

so I think it will be like:

```
var tomato = SOMETHING HERE MYSTERY DIFFICULT!!!!;
for (var i = 0; i < tomato; i++) {
WINDOW COUNTER HERE (EASY)
  }
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator) - a snippet from MDC:

```
var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                   .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
var enumerator = wm.getEnumerator(type);
while(enumerator.hasMoreElements()) {
  var win = enumerator.getNext();
  // win is [Object ChromeWindow] (just like window), do something with it
}
```

Comment: use "navigator:browser" (with quotes) in place of `type`, and you can use `win.gBrowser.browsers.length`  to get number of tabs in each window.